# how to execute a console application in Surface RT

Tags: console

I had created a simple "Hello World" application in C and cross compiled for ARM using Visual Studio 2012 and copied the application to Surface RT. When I tried to execute the "Hello World" application from command prompt, following error message is displayed.

Err Msg: "The system cannot execute the specified program".

Can any one suggest how to execute an application in Surface RT?

Note: I'm not using windows store apps just a console application. Also I have converted DLL taken from surface RT to Library and copied to \Visual Studio11.0\VC\Lib\arm\ (local machine where I'm compiling the source code)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You cant run only Windows Store Applications (or Digitally Signed by Microsoft applications i.e. MS Office/Skype) on Surface RT

Windows RT does not run any other apps even if its ARM architecture application!

Only way is to Jailbreak, but Jailbreak tool itself is broken after updates from Microsoft :)

So, you are struck! till MS opens Surface RT for other apps or new Jailbreak tool is made available.